# Como trocar um apply dentro de um for por um apply duplo?

Tags: r, for, apply

Tenho um vetor `origem` e um vetor `destino` com diversas localizações em latitude e longitude.

Para cada local em `origem`, quero contar quantos locais em `destino` estão localizados em um raio de até 2km, e pra isso fiz uma função que calcula as distancias `distanciaEmKm(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)`.

Eu então resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(destino)) {

  dists <- mapply(distanceLatLongKm, origem$LAT[i], origem$LONG[i], destino$LAT, destino$LONG)
  origem$ATE_2KM[i] <- sum(dists <= 2)

}
```

Então gostaria de saber se existe uma outra maneira e evitar esse `for` e fazer com que já rodasse para todas as linhas de ambos vetores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma possível é gerar todas as combinações possíveis e depois aplicar o apply normal. As combinações podem ser geradas usando algo como `expand.grid` ou assim usando o pacote `purrr`.

Considere `origem` e `destino` `lists` ou `data.frames` assim:

```
origem <- list(
  id = 1:10,
  lat = 1:10,
  long = 1:10
)

destino <- list(
  id = 1:11,
  lat = 10:20,
  long = 10:20
)
```

Assim você obtem todas as combinações:

```
library(purrr)
todas_combinacoes <- list(origem = origem, destino = destino) %>%
  map(transpose) %>% 
  cross_n()
```

Agora você pode aplicar a função que quiser usando `mutate` do `dplyr`. Para a distância, por exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)
todas_combinacoes %>%
  mutate(
    id_origem = map_int(origem, ~.x$id),
    id_destino = map_int(destino, ~.x$id),
    distancia = map2_dbl(origem, destino, ~distanciaEmKm(.x$lat, .x$long, .y$lat, .y$long))
  ) %>%
  group_by(id_origem) %>%
  summarise(sum(distancia <= 2))
```

É improvável que essa seja a solução mais simples/ com menos linhas de código. Mas, pensar dessa forma ajuda a fazer diversas outras análises, como você pode encontrar [aqui](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1)

Comment: Opa, valeu denovo Falbel! Além da resposta ao problema original, achei muito interessante a ideia de list-column. Já tive problemas onde tive que rodar o código várias vezes para pegar diferentes informações, mas nunca tive a ideia de armazenar em lista. Valeu!